# Problem: textbox does not fire its TextChanged event after typing some text?

Tags: asp.net, textbox, drop-down-menu

I have a we form (.aspx) that has several controls such as dropdownlist, textbox(textbox1), ...

The dropdownlist's autopostback is true and when I change the selected index of it, based on what index I have selected, a text is written in textbox1 and then because the autopostback of textbox1 is true, 2 other textboxes fill themselves based on the text written in textbox1.

But surprisingly, when I type some text directy in textbox1, the textchanged event of it doesn't fire.

why?

I use Asp.net 3.5, c#.

Comment: Give some of your markup and JS.

Comment: is this a server side, or client side event you are looking for?

Comment: I use Server-side event handling....

Answer (score 1):

Do you type the text and tab out of the textbox? The postback for a textbox occurs when it loses focus. Refer remark section of [TextBox.Autopostback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx).

Comment: yes, after typing in the textbox, I tab out of it but unfortunately the textchanged event hanlder doesn't fire. I will check the link you have written out. Thank you.